# -[__NSCFDictionary rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdictionary, nsrange

i know many solutions are available here for this problem but I am stuck on a single line which runs sometime successfully n crashes sometimes, i really dont know why this is happening.....

here is my code of posting mail in which i m getting the error `-[__NSCFDictionary rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

and here is my code of the method which is called on button pressed.

```
NSString* ingredientLine = [arrayOfIngredientList objectAtIndex:i];

NSArray* split ;

NSRange range = [ingredientLine rangeOfString:@"~"];

if (range.length > 0)
{
    split = [ingredientLine componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

    if( [split count] > 1 )
    {
        float amount = [[split objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

        float actualAmount = amount*((float)recipeServings/(float)4);

        //parse the float if its 1.00 it becomes only 1

        NSString* amnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", actualAmount];

        NSArray* temp = [amnt componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        if([[temp objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString: @"0"])

            amnt = [temp objectAtIndex:0];

        if( actualAmount == 0.0 )

            amnt = @"";

        [amnt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".0" withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"Amount is : %@",[split objectAtIndex:1]);

        strAmount = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",amnt,[split objectAtIndex:1]];

        NSLog(@"Ingredient is : %@", strAmount);

        strIngedient = [split objectAtIndex:2];

    }
    else //ingredients header
    {
        //[[cell viewWithTag:10] setHidden:YES];
        strIngedient = [split objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
else 
{

}

strIngredientsInfo = [strIngredientsInfo stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ - %@ </br>",strAmount,strIngedient];
```

App crashes due to

```
    NSArray* split ;

NSRange range = [ingredientLine rangeOfString:@"~"];

if (range.length > 0)
{
    split = [ingredientLine componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
    }
```

Please Help.

Please Suggest why it is crashing ???? :(

Comment: Where does `ingredientLine` come from? It looks like sometimes that is not an `NSString` but an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I added Inderdientline, it its a string which in obtaining by array of index..

Comment: Ok, so where is `arrayOfIngredientList` coming from? Are you certain the only objects in there are `NSString`s? (Gah someone removed the bit you added to show `arrayOfIngredientList`!)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - I think you removed an important update that @IphonyIphony added. Can you add it back please? (It was referring to `arrayOfIngredientList`).

Comment: @mattjgalloway it's back...  click on the "edited ____ minutes ago" link above my name to see what I changed in context, b.t.w.

Comment: Ah great thanks! Oh and ignore my edit, I got a bit carried away...

Comment: Can both of you suggest me any thing ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because sometimes this piece of code:

```
[arrayOfIngredientList objectAtIndex:i]
```

returns an instance of an `NSDictionary` instead of the `NSString` you are expecting. It does this because somewhere beforehand you have stored an `NSDictionary` in that array.

So, I don't know how big that array is and whether it's practical to print its entire contents out to see what's happening, but here's something to help you debug. In the piece where it's crashing, change it to this:

```
if ( ! [ingredientLine respondsToSelector:@selector(rangeOfString:)] ) {
    NSLog(@"ingredientLine is not an NSString! It is a: %@", ingredientLine);
} else {
    NSRange range = [ingredientLine rangeOfString:@"~"];
}
```

You can also put a breakpoint on the `NSLog` line to see what's happening. Note that this will stop your crashes, but it does *not* fix the underlying problem. This is just a suggestion to help you debug the real issue, which is that somewhere further up the line you are putting `NSDictionary` instances in your `arrayOfIngredientList`.

EDIT: Some explanation of what's happening here might help you. The `if` statement checks to see whether the object pointed to by `ingredientLine` does not respond to the message `rangeOfString:`.  Even though you've declared `ingredientLine` as an `NSString *`, you can easily assign it to an instance of a completely different class, in which case it won't be an `NSString` instance anymore and it won't be able to respond to `NSString`'s messages. Note that you could also say:

```
`if ( ! [ingredientList isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )`
```

Which would do the same job here. However I used `respondsToSelector:` as it's a very useful message to know about in Objective C.

Comment: Did you find out why you were putting `NSDictionary` instances in your array??