# Can't load all of my objects for my model (NSObject) from .plist

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, deserialization

**Hello.**

I have created model in my app where i have ShoppingList and Items class(NSObject).
Every item have just one ShoppingList and ShoppingList have more Items

(ShoppingList<-->>Items)

I already save all data to plist as NSArray and NSDictionary, but now i have problem load back my Items.

My plist:

```
Root (NSArray)->>

___________Item 0(Dictionary)->>

________________________date(Date),name(String),items(Array)->> ____________________________________________________Item 0(Dictionary)->>
________________________________________________________________date(Date),name(String)
```

And here is my code for write and read this plist:

```
- (NSDictionary *)propertyListRepresentation {
NSMutableArray *itemsAsPropertyLists = [NSMutableArray new];
for (Item *item in self.items) {
    NSDictionary *itemPropertyList = [item propertyListRepresentation];
    [itemsAsPropertyLists addObject:itemPropertyList];
}

return @{
         @"name": self.nameOfList ?: @"",
         @"date": self.date ?: [NSDate distantPast],
         @"items": itemsAsPropertyLists,
         };
}
+ (ShoppingList *)createFromPropertyListRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)plist {
ShoppingList *newList = [ShoppingList new];

newList.nameOfList = [plist objectForKey:@"name"];
newList.date = [plist objectForKey:@"date"];

return newList;
}
+ (NSArray *)loadPropertyList{
NSArray*loadData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Me/Desktop/saved.plist"];
NSMutableArray *shoppingLists = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSDictionary *loadDictionary in loadData) {
     ShoppingList *shoppingList = [ShoppingList createFromPropertyListRepresentation:loadDictionary];
    [shoppingLists addObject:shoppingList];

     for (NSArray *array in loadDictionary) {
          NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray new];
       itemsArray = [Item loadPropertyList:array];
       [shoppingLists addObject:itemsArray];
     }
}
return shoppingLists;
```

}

And for Item:

```
- (NSDictionary *)propertyListRepresentation {
return @{
         @"name": self.name ?: @" ",
        @"date" : self.date ?:[NSDate date],
         };
}
 +(Item*)createFromPropertyListRepresentation:(NSDictionary*)dict {
Item *newItems = [Item new];

newItems.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
newItems.date = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];

return newItems;
}
+(NSArray*)loadPropertyList:(NSArray*)array {
NSMutableArray *listOfItems = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary*dict in array) {
    Item *item = [Item createFromPropertyListRepresentation:dict];
    [listOfItems addObject:item];
    }

return listOfItems;
}
```

So this code work stop working on line

`Item *item = [Item createFromPropertyListRepresentation:dict];`

with the error:

```
-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: On this line: `for (NSArray *array in loadDictionary)` are you actually enumerating NSStrings?

Comment: Your problem is quite similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616705/nscfdictionary-rangeofstring-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance Read the answer there carefully and try to understand and implement it on your own code. (:

Comment: If i put there breakpoint it show me on that array @"name"

Comment: *Neeku  I don´t think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDictionary's implementation of NSFastEnumeration returns keys, not objects. Instead of `for (NSArray *array in loadDictionary)` you should do something along the lines of:

```
NSArray *itemPlist = [loadDictionary objectForKey: @"items"];
NSArray *items = [Item loadPropertyList: itemPlist];
[shoppingLists addObject: items];
```

But you might want to do something with the name and the date, too.